# MultipleObjectsReturned Django

Tags: django, sql, django-models

Quiero retornar los 2 o n coincidencias de registros 
que me aparecen pero me muestra la siguiente excepción

> Exception Value:
>
> get() returned more than one Archivo -- it returned 2!

La Query que retorna la excepción

```
queryModeloArchivo= Archivo.objects.get(modelo=query2Model, status=1)
queryArchivo= queryModeloArchivo.modelo
```

Si cambio la query a filter, con esta obtengo todos los registros es decir los 2 registros:

```
queryModeloArchivo= Archivo.objects.filter(modelo=query2Model, status=1)
```

Sin embargo ya no puedo acceder a las propiedades del modelo queryModeloArchivo es decir:

```
queryArchivo= queryModeloArchivo.modelo
```

Answer (score 2):

Ese error es debido a que la consulta que es utilizada en el metodo **get** debe retornar un solo registro no más. Por ejemplo cuando hacemos consultas por el **id** del elemento.

Para consultas en la el resultado es mas de un registro deberias usar el metodo **filter** del queryset y no get.

Desde La documentación:

> Django will complain if more than one item matches the
>   get() query. In this case, it will raise MultipleObjectsReturned,
>   which again is an attribute of the model class itself.

Basicamente dice que cuando la consulta returne mas de un objeto lanzara la excepción **MultipleObjectsReturned**

Debes tener en cuenta que cuando usas el metodo filter estas obteniendo un queryset y no el conjunto de elementos para obtener los elementos debes evaluar el queryset ya sea usando un slice o el metodo all de django.

queryset = Archivo.objects.filter(modelo=query2Model, status=1)

```
objetos = queryset.all()
```

o

```
objetos = queryset[0:]
```

o

```
for obj in queryset:
    # codigo aqui.
```

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve
>   any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long,
>   and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is
>   evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hace una consulta con `filter()` tienes que tener en cuenta que este te devuelve todo lo que machea con tu query en una lista, por lo tanto para acceder a las propiedades de un objeto debes o que recorrerlo con

```
...
for query in queryModeloArchivo:
    // Entonces aqui preguntas por las propiedades de cada uno
    queryArchivo = query.modelo
...
```